# Undefined index php by POST

Tags: php, mysql, undefined-index

I have my `ppf.php` file:

it has a form with some items,where I show data from my database, it works i have no problem with it.

```
<form name="pagar"  method="post" action="updaterecord.php">
<input type="text" name="num_paciente" size=40 maxlength=40 readonly value="<?php echo $fila['num_paciente']; ?>">// Here I show data from my data base // it works.
<input name="monto"  size=40 maxlength=40 type="text"  value="" required />
<textarea id="concepto" name="concepto" rows="5" cols="58" required></textarea>
..more input fields
 <input align="middle" type="submit" value="paga">
</form>
```

the problem is

`ppf.php` has a submit button, and my form is send to `updaterecord.php`.
In updaterecord.php i need to receive all values of my `ppf.php` to update a table in my Database:

```
<?php
$num_paciente=$_POST['num_paciente'];
$monto=$_POST['monto'];
$concepto=$_POST['concepto'];

$updater="UPDATE op SET monto = '$monto', concepto='$concepto', status='PAGADO' where num_paciente='".$num_paciente."'";
mysql_query($updater,$con)or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

It doesn't work: and I see it:

```
Notice: Undefined index: num_paciente in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\updaterecord.php on line 16    
Notice: Undefined index: monto in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\updaterecord.php on line 17    
Notice: Undefined index: concepto in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\updaterecord.php on line 18
```

How I can solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: As mentioned by Barry, you should specify the form to use POST method.  Also, please look up what SQL injection is.  http://php.net/manual/en/images/fa7c5b5f326e3c4a6cc9db19e7edbaf0-xkcd-bobby-tables.png

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what the script's really receiving.

Comment: @JustinKiang my code has it, (sorry, my mistake. I updated the question). And it dowsn't work...

Comment: Better yet, do a print_r($_REQUEST) just to see where everything is

Comment: How did you post it? I do not see a button. You use a button or JavaScript?

Comment: Or use inspect element in your webbrowser and check in network how the form(method and fields) is sent.

Comment: i have my button <input align="middle" type="submit" value="paga"> inside of my ppf.php file

Comment: @MarcB The S_POST brings my data: array(9), and num_paciente, monto y concepto have information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer of @Barry, your query must be corrected as this:

```
$updater="UPDATE op SET monto = '".$monto."', concepto='".$concepto."', status='PAGADO' where num_paciente='".$num_paciente."'";
```

I read again your code, please be careful to the textarea, change this:

```
<input type="text" name="num_paciente" size=40 maxlength=40
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="num_paciente" size="40" maxlength="40"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<form method="post">
```

to send the form values with a post action. The default method is "get".
You can also get the values with `$_GET` in your php script.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't put it here , in the question , but the code has it

Comment: The button is inside of my form on ppf.php